# Ubuntu keeps freezing randomly?

Tags: 18.04, permissions, lts

I'll be doing simple processes or just moving the mouse then it freezes.
It isn't on any specific program it freezes on.
I've provided some logs that hopefully someone can understand better then me to fix this problem.

Thanks!

### System info

Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Memory:    3.7 GiB
Processor: Intel pentium(R) CPU N3540 @ 2.16GHz x 4
Graphics:  Intel Bay Trail
GNOME:     3.28.2
OS type:   64-bit
Disk:      491.2 GB

### /var/log/syslog

```
Aug 12 04:38:58 Travis-HP-15-Notebook-PC gvfsd[1330]: message repeated 27 times: [ mkdir failed on directory /var/cache/samba: Permission denied]
Aug 12 04:38:59 Travis-HP-15-Notebook-PC code.desktop[1960]: #033[91m[main 2019-08-12T09:38:59.070Z]#033[0m [Error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED]
Aug 12 04:38:59 Travis-HP-15-Notebook-PC code.desktop[1960]: #033[90m[main 2019-08-12T09:38:59.079Z]#033[0m update#setState idle
Aug 12 04:38:59 Travis-HP-15-Notebook-PC gvfsd[1330]: mkdir failed on directory /var/cache/samba: Permission denied
Aug 12 04:38:59 Travis-HP-15-Notebook-PC gvfsd[1330]: mkdir failed on directory /var/cache/samba: Permission denied
Aug 12 04:41:29 Travis-HP-15-Notebook-PC dbus-daemon[1174]: [session uid=1000 pid=1174] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.120' (uid=1000 pid=2319 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.real " label="unconfined")
Aug 12 04:41:29 Travis-HP-15-Notebook-PC systemd[986]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
Aug 12 04:41:30 Travis-HP-15-Notebook-PC dbus-daemon[1174]: [session uid=1000 pid=1174] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
Aug 12 04:41:30 Travis-HP-15-Notebook-PC systemd[986]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
Aug 12 04:42:04 Travis-HP-15-Notebook-PC gnome-shell[1301]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/notificationDaemon.js 121]: reference to undefined property "image-path"
```

### /var/log/kern.log

```
Aug 12 04:45:31 Travis-HP-15-Notebook-PC kernel: [  637.702624] wlo1: associated
Aug 12 04:45:50 Travis-HP-15-Notebook-PC canonical-livepatch[932]: error in livepatch check state: check-failed
Aug 12 04:46:27 Travis-HP-15-Notebook-PC canonical-livepatch[932]: error in livepatch check state: check-failed
Aug 12 04:46:28 Travis-HP-15-Notebook-PC canonical-livepatch[932]: Client.Check
Aug 12 04:46:29 Travis-HP-15-Notebook-PC canonical-livepatch[932]: error in livepatch check state: check-failed
Aug 12 04:46:29 Travis-HP-15-Notebook-PC canonical-livepatch[932]: Checking with livepatch service.
Aug 12 04:46:29 Travis-HP-15-Notebook-PC canonical-livepatch[932]: updating last-check
Aug 12 04:46:29 Travis-HP-15-Notebook-PC canonical-livepatch[932]: touched last check
Aug 12 04:46:29 Travis-HP-15-Notebook-PC canonical-livepatch[932]: No updates available at this time.
Aug 12 04:46:29 Travis-HP-15-Notebook-PC canonical-livepatch[932]: No payload available.
```

Comment: it reads more like a hardware problem to me, have you evaluated/tested your hardware to ensure it's not the problem?  You also provided no times (or for how long) the freezing takes place?  Are you talking tens-seconds, minutes, hours or it never comes back?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a time of freeze. Sometimes it will work for an hour, and sometimes 2 to 3 hours. It will stay frozen until I restart my computer. I'll check my hardware though, I didn't think of that thanks.

Comment: The only thing I found with my hardware was my computer display OpenGL was in an unkown state.

Comment: When I said checking hardware I was thinking of boot a 'live' system (I would opt for something completely different to what you normally use; very different kernel etc) and letting it sit for a day to see if it locks up or remains 'ready'. I'd also run memtest86 a couple of times, and even open the box and do a cap-check (ie. scan of motherboard, looking for any swollen capacitors or signs of heat stress or component failure. With what you're describing I would say 50% chance it would fail a cap-check; hence my hardware suggestion...

Comment: Oh, gotcha. I'll try a different kernel. Also, it's a laptop not a desktop tower. I've never opened up a laptop before so I'm not to sure how comfortable I'd be doing it. I appreciate your help and I'm new to Linux systems, but I'm learning.